# How to resolve maximum call stack size error on Vercel deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I built a Google docs clone for which you can find the Github repo [here](https://github.com/jevoncochran/google-docs-clone). Everything seeems to work fine locally. However, I have been unable to use the app after deploying with Vercel. As soon as I log in, it takes me to the home page which flashes and then breaks showing the maximum call stack size exceeded error. Any ideas as to how to resolve this? Also, why would this only be happening in prod and not local?

This is what my home page file looks like:

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { BsThreeDotsVertical } from "react-icons/bs";
import { Dialog, Button } from "@/lib/materialTailwind";
import axios from "axios";
import db from "@/firebase/config";
import { collection, onSnapshot, query } from "firebase/firestore";
import DocumentRow from "@/components/DocumentRow";
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import { Document } from "@/types";

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [newDocumentTitle, setNewDocumentTitle] = useState("");
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState<Document[]>([]);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setShowModal(!showModal);
  };

  const createDcoument = () => {
    axios
      .post("/api/docs", { fileName: newDocumentTitle })
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));

    setNewDocumentTitle("");
    toggleModal();
  };

  const newDocModal = (
    <Dialog
      size="xs"
      open={showModal}
      handler={toggleModal}
      className="bg-white shadow-none h-[200px] p-5 flex flex-col justify-between"
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        value={newDocumentTitle}
        onChange={(e) => setNewDocumentTitle(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter name of document..."
        onKeyDown={(e) => e.key === "Enter" && createDcoument()}
        className="outline-none w-full"
      />
      <div>
        <Button
          onClick={toggleModal}
          className="bg-transparent shadow-none hover:shadow-none text-blue-600"
        >
          CANCEL
        </Button>
        <Button color="blue" className="ml-4" onClick={createDcoument}>
          CREATE
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Dialog>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, `userDocs/${session?.user?.email}/docs`));

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      let docArr: Document[] = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
        docArr.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      setDocuments(docArr);

      return () => unsubscribe();
    });
  }, [session?.user?.email]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {newDocModal}
      <section className="bg-[#F0F3F4] pb-10 px-10">
        <div className="max-w-3xl mx-auto">
          <div className="py-6 flex justify-between items-center">
            <h2 className="text-gray-700 text-lg">Create a new document</h2>
            <BsThreeDotsVertical size="1.2em" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Image
              src={
                "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/templates/thumbnails/docs-blank-googlecolors.png"
              }
              alt="new Google Jock"
              height={150}
              width={150}
              onClick={toggleModal}
              className="border-2 rounded-md cursor-pointer hover:border hover:border-blue-500"
            />
            <p className="mt-2 font-semibold text-sm text-gray-700">Blank</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div className="max-w-3xl mx-auto py-8">
          <table className="table-auto w-full">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Previous 30 Days</th>
                <th>Owned by anyone</th>
                <th>Last opened by me</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {documents.map((doc) => (
                <DocumentRow key={doc.id} doc={doc} />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]